# What does grep classifier in Open vSwitch mean?

Tags: grep, mininet, openflow, openvswitch

I use `ovs-ofctl dump-tables s_id` when I want to show the flow table stats. Sometimes I notice 'grep classifier' is used as (`ovs-ofctl dump-tables s_id | grep classifier`). What does **grep classifier** mean?

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Introduction

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`man grep`

> grep searches input files for lines containing a match to a given pattern list.